# The Xamarin AXML Designer isn't working; an error occurs. How can I fix this so I can use the designer?

Tags: android, xamarin

I really want to use the designer, but errors are stopping me

> "Something went wrong; The operation Load failed due to an internal
>   error: .": java.lang.NullPointerException     at
>   mono.android.DesignerException.fromThrowable(DesignerException.java:30)
>     at
>   mono.android.DesignerSession.checkRenderResultForError(DesignerSession.java:187)
>     at mono.android.DesignerSession.load(DesignerSession.java:239)  at
>   mono.android.DesignerSession.processMessage(DesignerSession.java:704)
>     at
>   mono.android.MessageListener.executeMessage(MessageListener.java:88)
>     at mono.android.MessageListener$Runner.run(MessageListener.java:44)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

It was working before, but suddenly I can't use the designer at all! Would it have anything to do with my turning debugging off to upload it to Google Play? I do think I turned everything back on and restarted Xamarin.